# select results from two tables but choose one field over another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables.

```
tblEmployee                  tblExtraOrMissingInfo

id nvarchar(10)              id nvarchar(10)
Name nvarchar(50)            Name nvarchar(50)
                             PreferredName nvarchar(50)
                             UsePreferredName bit
```

The data (brief example)

```
 tblEmployee                 tblExtraOrMissingInfo
 id     Name                 id     Name         PreferredName   UsePreferredName 
 AB12   John                 PN01   Peter        Tom             1
 LM22   Lisa                 YH76   Andrew       Andy            0
 PN01   Peter                LM22   Lisa         Liz             0
 LK655  Sarah
```

I want a query to produce the following result

```
 id     Name
 AB12   John
 LM22   Lisa
 PN01   Tom 
 YH76   Andrew
 LK655  Sarah
```

So what I want is all the records from tblEmployee returned and any records in tblExtraOrMissingInfo that are not already in tblEmployee.

If there is a record in both tables with the same id I would like is if the UsePreferredName field in tblExtraOrMissingInfo is 1 for the PreferredName to be used rather than the Name field in the tblEmployee, please see the record PN01 in the example above.

Comment: Please google and learn about the UNION keyword in SQL Server.

Comment: @TabAlleman -- Not only is it obnoxious to tell people to google, you are wrong UNION does not help in this case.

Comment: Apologies, I did not see the bit about the UsePreferredName flag in my first read-thru.   A UNION **could** be used to reach a solution, but it would not be the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is slightly faster to use a left join and coalesce than to use the case statement (most servers are optimized for coalesce).

Like this:

```
 SELECT E.ID, COALESCE(P.PreferredName,E.Name,'Unknown') as Name
 FROM tblemployee E
 LEFT JOIN tblExtraOrMissingInfo P ON E.ID = P.ID AND P.UsePreferredName = 1
```

> The `,'Unknown'` is not needed to answer your question, but I added
>   here to show that you can enhance this query to handle cases where the
>   name is not available in both tables and you don't want nulls in your result

Comment: . . This is the right answer, but I would leave out the `Unknown` and just let the value be `NULL` with no match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- yeah... that is how I originally had it, but I wanted to show the user that this solution can be "enhanced" simply to handle the unknown case... added a comment to make that clear

Answer (score 2):

`left join` on the employee table and use a `case` expression for name.

```
select e.id
,case when i.UsePreferredName = 1 then i.PreferredName else e.name end as name
from tblemployee e
left join tblExtraOrMissingInfo i on i.id=e.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the tables together, then use a `CASE` statement and `COALESCE()` formula to get this:

```
SELECT
    tblEmployee.id,
    CASE WHEN UsePreferredName = 1 THEN COALESCE(PreferredName, tblEmployee.Name) ELSE tblEmployee.name
FROM 
    tblEmployee
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblExtraOrMissingInfo 
        ON tblEmployee.id = tblExtraOrMissingInfo.id
```

`CASE` checks that `usePreferredName` value, and the `COALESCE()` then grabs `PreferredName` unless it's NULL. Then it grabs the employees name from tblEmployee.

Answer (score -1):

```
select id ,name 
from
(
select  id ,name from tblEmployee 
union all
select id ,name from tblExtraOrMissingInfo
)group by id,name
```

Comment: With UNION instead of UNION ALL, the Group by is unnecessary.   And by the way, this will produce an error since the derived table is not aliased.

Comment: This also will give the wrong result since there is no handing of the flag

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

This is an other way you can achieve the results. You can also use CTE to get the same result.

```
CREATE TABLE #tblEmployee
    (
      id NVARCHAR(10)
    , Name NVARCHAR(50)
    );

CREATE TABLE #tblExtraOrMissingInfo
    (
      id NVARCHAR(10)
    , Name NVARCHAR(50)
    , PreferredName NVARCHAR(50)
    , UsePreferredName BIT
    );

INSERT  INTO #tblEmployee
        ( id, Name )
VALUES  ( N'AB12'  -- id - nvarchar(10)
          , N'John'  -- Name - nvarchar(50)
          ),
        ( N'LM22'  -- id - nvarchar(10)
          , N'Lisa'  -- Name - nvarchar(50)
          ),
        ( N'PN01'  -- id - nvarchar(10)
          , N'Peter'  -- Name - nvarchar(50)
          ),
        ( N'LK655'  -- id - nvarchar(10)
          , N'Sarah'  -- Name - nvarchar(50)
          );

INSERT  INTO #tblExtraOrMissingInfo
        ( id, Name, PreferredName, UsePreferredName )
VALUES  ( N'PN01'  -- id - nvarchar(10)
          , N'Peter'  -- Name - nvarchar(50)
          , N'Tom'  -- PreferredName - nvarchar(50)
          , 1  -- UsePreferredName - bit
          ),
        ( N'YH76'  -- id - nvarchar(10)
          , N'Andrew'  -- Name - nvarchar(50)
          , N'Andy'  -- PreferredName - nvarchar(50)
          , 0  -- UsePreferredName - bit
          ),
        ( N'LM22'  -- id - nvarchar(10)
          , N'Lisa'  -- Name - nvarchar(50)
          , N'Liz'  -- PreferredName - nvarchar(50)
          , 0  -- UsePreferredName - bit
          );

SELECT  R.id
      , CASE WHEN tbl.UsePreferredName = 1 THEN tbl.PreferredName
             ELSE R.Name
        END AS NAME
FROM    #tblExtraOrMissingInfo tbl
        RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT id
                          , Name
                     FROM   #tblEmployee
                     UNION
                     SELECT id
                          , Name
                     FROM   #tblExtraOrMissingInfo
                   ) AS R
        ON R.id = tbl.id
           AND R.Name = tbl.Name;
```

Comment: Because you are using a union here you will get the wrong results even if you fix the bugs (the join is wrong).  Also your comment is wrong, you are not using a CTE for anything but creating test data.

Comment: @Hogan: Thank you for taking time to write a comment. Could you please explain what's wrong in the join. I was trying to say you can use CTE to get the desired result. I was not saying that I am using CTE to get my result. This is the result I am getting with my query above.        id NAME
AB12 John
LK655 Sarah
LM22 Lisa
PN01 Tom
YH76 Andrew

Comment: you are not using a cte to get any part of this result.  in order for there to be a cte there would need to be a "with" keyword.

Comment: this query can't be correct your join is as follows `ON R.id = tbl.id  AND R.Name = tbl.Name;`  There is **nothing in the model** that suggests joining on name would be correct.  id is clearly the key.  *Why are you joining on name?*

Comment: Thank you for the response. About the CTE. I am not saying that I am using a CTE, I am just saying you can use the concept of CTE.  I understand what you mean by the incorrect join now. Thank you for the explanation.